# How to summarize the rewards of a "lottery" sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I play a game where we can collect a certain type of resource, let's say it is money. With a certain amount of money we can buy a sort of lottery ticket. The ticket either gives back some money or gives other types of resources with certain chances. So what we have is something like:

```
B[money]      balance 
T[function]   ticket
   p[money]   the price of the ticket
   rm[money]  money reward
   cm[%]      chance of winning the money reward
   rx[x]      resource x reward
   cx[%]      chance of winning the resource x reward
   ry[y]      resource y reward
   cy[%]      chance of winning the resource y reward
   rz[z]      resource z reward
   cz[%]      chance of winning the resource z reward
   ...
```

We can buy tickets until we run out of money and there are different types of tickets we can choose from. The goal is comparing tickets and choosing the right one for winning the most type "x" resources. It really depends on the players needs which resource is more important for them so for others "y" might be more useful. I want to compare tickets to be able to decide which one to choose for my needs.

For a comparison I need to know how much rewards I can expect from them when I start with a certain amount of money. For now what I did is using a random number generator and buying tickets until I ran out of money. After that I start over, and I do this for example 10k times. I end up with a multi dimensional reward distribution:

$$
T_p(B) = \{
  a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z + ...,
  a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 z + ...,
  ...
  a_{10000} x + b_{10000} y + c_{10000} z + ...
\}
$$

After that I calculate average and standard deviation for each resources and end up with a statistics something like the following with for example 68% confidence:

$$S(T_p(B)) = (avg(a_i) \pm stdev(a_i))x + (avg(b_i) \pm stdev(b_i))y + (avg(c_i) \pm stdev(c_i))z + ...$$

I am not sure if standard deviation is valid here. Is it?

With the average I can compare my chests so for example if "x" is the most important resource, then a comparison is something simple like:

$$S(T_p).avg.x > S(T_q).avg.x$$

Which means ticket "p" gives more resource "x" than ticket "q", so I have to choose ticket "p" over ticket "q".

What I want to do is figuring out the formula for the upper results. For certain tickets it is trivial to count the average, because they don't give back any money $r_m = 0, x_m = 0$.

$$S(T(B)).{avg} = B/p \cdot [ (r_x \cdot c_x)x + (r_y \cdot c_y)y + (r_z \cdot c_z)z + ... ]$$

Here the number of drawing lots is $L = B/p$. It is possible to count this number for a ticket that gives back money too. We have a series there:

$$L(B) = B/p + L(r_m \cdot c_m \cdot B/p)$$
$$L(B) = B/p \cdot [1 + (r_m \cdot c_m) / p + ((r_m \cdot c_m)/p)^2 + ((r_m \cdot c_m)/p)^3 + ... ]$$
$$L(B) = B/p \cdot \sum_{i=0}^\infty{((r_m \cdot c_m)/p)^i}$$

For this kind of series we can use the following solution:

$$L(B) \cdot [1 - ((r_m \cdot c_m)/p)] = B/p \cdot [1 - ((r_m \cdot c_m)/p)^\infty]$$
$$0 < (r_m \cdot c_m)/p < 1$$
$$L(B) = \frac{B/p}{1 - (r_m \cdot c_m)/p} = \frac{B}{p - r_m \cdot c_m}$$

This works pretty well for the average number of drawing lots, but I am not sure how do I get the average for the rewards. Should I just multiply this with the chances and rewards like I did in the trivial case?

$$S(T(B)).{avg} = \frac{B}{p - r_m \cdot c_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot c_x)x + (r_y \cdot c_y)y + (r_z \cdot c_z)z + ... ]$$

I guess this is right, so this is the easy question.

The hard question is how do I get information about the distribution? So what kind of distribution do we have here and how can I describe it?

The $0 < (r_m \cdot c_m)/p < 1$ is always true, but $r_m > p$ is possible in the case of some tickets, so it is possible to win more money than we spend on the ticket. Which means it is possible to buy certain tickets infinite times $L_{max}(B) = \infty$ with a zero chance, while there are tickets which can we win only a finite times $L_{max}(B) \neq \infty$.

The $L_{min}(B) = B/p$ is trivial again. I think I can calculate the probability for these corner cases, but I have no idea about how to calculate the probability for the $L(B)$ values that are not average, min or max. I can get the same L value in many possible ways and for me it is a little confusing to work through all of these permutations. Even if I manage to somehow calculate the probabilities for different $L(B)$ values, I have no idea how I can calculate the chance and reward distributions even for these corner cases. For me knowing the $S(T(B)).{avg}$ is enough and probably the formula I wrote for it is ok, I just want to know if it is possible to say anything about the distributions without doing a simulation and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out meanwhile, but it is a complex question. We need some tools here from statistics and [enumerative combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_combinatorics).

I have the upper formula for average:

$$S(T(B)).{avg} = \frac{B}{p - r_m \cdot c_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot c_x)x + (r_y \cdot c_y)y + (r_z \cdot c_z)z + ... ]$$

I want to change the symbols here, and I would rather use

- $p$ for probability instead of $c$ for chance
- $c_t$ for ticket costs instead of $p$ for ticket price
- $m0$ money at the beginning instead of $B$ balance
- avoid dot for properties.

So the upper formula looks like the following with the new symbols:

$$S_{avg}(T(m_0)) = \frac{m_0}{c_t - r_m \cdot p_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... ]$$

I checked and it certainly works for the average, but for the distribution it is useless. I don't know if there is any shortcut for the distribution, I just thought it through with a brute force method sort of and tried to reuse certain recurring patterns.

#### 1.) How many time can we draw lots with what probability?

First we need to deal with the ever changing $L$ number, which represents the number of drawing lots. In the upper formula we are talking about average too.

$$L_{avg} = \frac{m_0}{c_t - r_m \cdot p_m}$$

The exact number is unknown, because it depends on the $r_m$ and the $c_m$. If we are lucky, then we can draw more lots if we can win back our money. We can talk about the minimum and the maximum numbers here. We got the minimum if we never win back money and we got the maximum if we always win back money.

$$L_{min} = floor(m_0/c_t)$$

$$
L_{max}(m=m_0) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & m < c_t\\
\infty & r_m > c_t\\
floor(m/c_t) + L_{max}(m\%c_t + floor(m/c_t) \cdot r_m) & otherwise
\end{array}\right.
$$

Everything is in-between these two edge cases.

$$L_{min} \leq L \leq L_{max}$$

I assume that we can count the average from this too, though in the case of $L_{max} = \infty$ we need to draw the line somewhere. I guess we need to check how much probability we have left from $p(L \leq L_{max}) = 100\%$ and draw the line around $p(L \leq L_{max}) = 99.9\%$, ofc. this is arbitrary. I guess this method works sometimes even with an $r_m \cdot p_m >= c_t$ here if $m_0$ is low enough, because with each cycle we increase the $p(L \leq L_{max})$ value, though we need to be careful, because we can easily end up with an ifinite loop.

$$L_{avg} = \sum_{L=L_{min}}^{L_{max}}{p(L) \cdot L}$$

I don't think we have a shortcut to count probability for $L$ because we cannot be sure what scenarios leads there. Let's call the number of drawing lots where we got money reward $L_m$. We can count the probability of a certain $L$ and $L_m$ pair this way:

$$p(L,L_m) = p_m^{L_m} \cdot (1-p_m)^{(L-L_m)}$$

But if we think about it, then this formula does not work in the case of $r_m > 0$, because these events are not necessarily independent from each other. For example if $m_0 = 4 \cdot c_t$ and $r_m = 1/2 \cdot c_t$, then

$$L_{min} = 4$$
$$L_{max} = 7$$

If we start with $L = 4$ and with $L_m = 0$ and increase $L_m$ with 1 in each cycle, then we soon run into a problem, because in the case of $L_m = 2$ we can draw lots another time. So certain permutations just don't exist here. I try to express this with sequences and unordered lists:

$$\{0,0,1,1\} \rightarrow (\{0,0,1,1\},0),(\{0,0,1,1\},1)$$
$$p(L=4,L_m=2) = 0 \neq (1/2)^2 \cdot (1-1/2)^{(4-2)}$$

So only $L = 5$ can exist with $L_m = 2$. But if we check, then we don't have all the permutations for $L = 5$ and $L_m = 2$, because if we don't win 2 in the first 4 times, then we won't have enough money to draw lots a 5th time and win money there.

$$\{0,0,0,1\} \nrightarrow (\{0,0,0,1\},1)$$
$$p(L=5,L_m=2) < (1/2)^2 \cdot (1-1/2)^{(5-2)}$$

So if we want to know the real probabilities we need a hierarchical approach and start with scenarios that certainly happen. We need a loops here just like in the formula of $L_{max}$ and work only with the money we currently have.

$$p(\{0,0,0,0\}) = (1-p_m)^4$$
$$p(\{0,0,0,1\}) = p_m \cdot (1-p_m)^3$$
$$p(\{0,0,1,1,...\}) = p_m^2 \cdot (1-p_m)^2$$
$$p(\{0,1,1,1,...\}) = p_m^3 \cdot (1-p_m)$$
$$p(\{1,1,1,1,...\}) = p_m^4$$

After this first cycle we ended up with some leaves and some branches and we can continue to grow our tree.

$$p(\{0,0,1,1,...\}) = p_m^2 \cdot (1-p_m)^2$$

If we continue with winning money, then

$$p((\{0,0,1,1\},1)) = p(\{0,0,1,1,...\}) \cdot p_m$$

On the other hand if we continue with not winning money, then

$$p((\{0,0,1,1\},0)) = p(\{0,0,1,1,...\}) \cdot (1-p_m)$$

In both cases we cannot continue further, because we don't have enough money to be able to draw lots one more time. If we could continue e.g. in the case of $(\{0,1,1,1,...\},1)$, then again we could count the probability for $(\{0,1,1,1\},1,0)$ and $(\{0,1,1,1\},1,1)$ and we would stop there after running out of money.

So for example if we want to know $p(L=6,L_m=4)$, then we need to sum up the probability of all leaves where that composition happens.

$$
p(L=6,L_m=4) = p(\{0,0,1,1,1,1\}) = \\
p((\{1,1,1,1\},0,0)) + p((\{0,1,1,1\},1,0)) + p((\{0,0,1,1\},1,1)) = \\
p(\{1,1,1,1\,...\}) \cdot p((0,0)) + p(\{0,1,1,1,...\}) \cdot p((1,0)) + p(\{0,0,1,1,...\}) \cdot p((1,1))
$$

Note that in this example the order matters, because we are talking about unordered lists and sequences.

$$
p(\{0,1\}) = p((0,1)) + p((1,0))
$$

In our example $(\{0,1,1,1\},1,0)$ exists, while $(\{0,1,1,1\},0,1)$ is non-existent, because we need to win money 4 times in 5 to be able to draw lots a 6th time.

Okay, so we counted the probabilities for different $L$ and $L_m$ pairs. We can calculate the probabilities for $L$ and $L_m$ individually too by summing up the probabilities of their pairs.

$$p(L) = \sum_{L_m = 0}^{L}{p(L,L_m)}$$

$$p(L_m) = \sum_{L = L_{min}}^{L_{max}}{p(L,L_m)}$$

#### 2.) What do we win with what probabilities?

In my case this is tricky, because I have another extra constant reward, which I calculate this way:

$$S_{e_{avg}}(T(m_0)) = \sum_{L=L_{min}}^{L_{max}}{(p(L) \cdot L \cdot r_e)e}$$

Or we can draw a distribution for it based on the results:

$$S_{e}(T(m_0)) = (p(L), (L \cdot r_e)e)$$

As of the other non-money rewards I have to use the drawing lots where I did not win money, so

$$L_{(x,y,z,...)} = L - L_m$$

We can count probabilities for this too:

$$p(L_{(x,y,z,...)}) = \sum_{L = L_{min}}^{L_{max}}{p(L,(L_m=L-L_{(x,y,z,...)}))}$$

For a certain $L_{(x,y,z,...)}$ we have 100% probability of winning something different than money $L_{(x,y,z,...)}$ times. So $p_x + p_y + p_z = 1$ and $p_m = 0$ for these scenarios. I believe the relative probabilities stay the same, so

$$p(x)/p(y) = p_2(x)/p_2(y)$$
$$p_2(x) = p_x/(1-p_m)$$

If this is the case, then we can count the average for different rewards:

$$S_{avg}(T(m_0)) = \sum_{L_{(x,y,z,...)}=0}^{L_{max}}{p(L_{(x,y,z,...)}) \cdot L_{(x,y,z,...)} \cdot [\frac{r_x \cdot p_x}{(1-p_m)}x + \frac{r_y \cdot p_y}{(1-p_m)}y + \frac{r_z \cdot p_z}{(1-p_m)}z + ...]}$$

We can simplify this further because we multiply with constants by summing up:

$$S_{avg}(T(m_0)) = \frac{\sum_{L_{(x,y,z,...)}=0}^{L_{max}}{p(L_{(x,y,z,...)}) \cdot L_{(x,y,z,...)}}}{1-p_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... ]$$

Which is very similar to what we started with.

$$S_{avg}(T(m_0)) = \frac{m_0}{c_t - r_m \cdot p_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... ]$$

So we have a new equation, which is sort of trivial if we think about it:

$$L_{(x,y,z,...)_{avg}} = \frac{m_0}{c_t - r_m \cdot p_m} \cdot (1-p_m) = L_{avg} \cdot (1-p_m)$$

We can draw a distribution for these the following way:

$$S(T(m_0)) = (p(L_{(x,y,z,...)}),  \frac{L_{(x,y,z,...)}}{1-p_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... ])$$

If we want to draw this with $S_e$ too, then it is somewhat more complicated:

$$S(T(m_0)) = (p(L, L_m), (L \cdot r_e)e + \frac{L - L_m}{1-p_m} \cdot [ (r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... ])$$

Thought we still have an average here for $x,y,z,...$ for each $L$ and $L_m$ pair. We can get the real probability here for the certain reward permutations by doing the following:

$$S(T(m_0)) = (p(L, L_m), (L \cdot r_e)e + [\frac{(r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ... }{1-p_m}]^{L - L_m})$$

It is possible to expand the $[(r_x \cdot p_x)x + (r_y \cdot p_y)y + (r_z \cdot p_z)z + ...]^{L - L_m}$, because it is the same as expanding $(a + b + c + ...)^n$ where $a = (r_x \cdot p_x)x$, $b = (r_y \cdot p_y)y$, $z = (r_z \cdot p_z)z$ and $n = L - L_m$.

Let's call $s = (a, b, c, d, ...)$, so if we multiply these $n$ times we will end up with $|s|^n$ permutations, which we could draw in an n-dimensional square matrix or we can draw it in $|s|^{n-2}$ 2d tables too:

```
a_  | a^2  | ab   | ac   | ad   | ...
--- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---
a   | a^3  | a^2b | a^2c | a^2d | ...
b   | a^2b | ab^2 | abc  | abd  | ...
c   | a^2c | abc  | ac^2 | acd  | ...
d   | a^2d | abd  | acd  | ad^2 | ...
... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...

b_  | ab   | b^2  | bc   | bd   | ...
--- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---
a   | a^2b | ab^2 | abc  | abd  | ...
b   | ab^2 | b^3  | b^2c | b^2d | ...
c   | abc  | b^2c | bc^2 | bcd  | ...
d   | abd  | b^2d | bcd  | bd^2 | ...
... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...

c_  | ac   | bc   | c^2  | cd   | ...
--- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---
a   | a^2c | abc  | ac^2 | acd  | ...
b   | abc  | b^2c | bc^2 | bcd  | ...
c   | ac^2 | bc^2 | c^3  | c^2d | ...
d   | acd  | bcd  | c^2d | cd^2 | ...
... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...

d_  | ad   | bd   | cd   | d^2  | ...
--- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---
a   | a^2d | abd  | acd  | ad^2 | ...
b   | abd  | b^2d | bcd  | bd^2 | ...
c   | acd  | bcd  | c^2d | cd^2 | ...
d   | ad^2 | bd^2 | cd^2 | d^3  | ...
... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...

...
```

If we do so we realize, that the upper formula is wrong. Well I am not sure how to explain it. Here we have one $a^3$ in our table and we have $4^3 = 64$ permutations. So the probability of having $a^3$ is $1/64$. Now if we check it with our original example $((r_x \cdot p_x)x)^3 = ({r_x}^3 \cdot {p_x}^3)x^3$, which is not what we need. What we really need in this scenario is $((3 \cdot {r_x}x) \cdot (1 \cdot {p_x}^3))$. If we check another scenario, for example $a^2c$, then we have it 3 times in our table, so we have $(2 \cdot {r_x}x + 1 \cdot {r_z}z) \cdot (3 \cdot {p_x}^2 \cdot p_z)$ there. Now writing down the exact formula of this with the language of math is beyond my abilities currently, but I guess you get what I mean. What we really have here is $(p_x + p_y + p_z + p_q)^3$ and the quantity of the reward depends on the power of the probability. If we check, we don't really need the $r_x$ value, the $x$ would be enough here, but in my case I can have multiple ${r_x}_i$ values with multiple ${p_x}_i$ probabilities, that's why I need it.

#### Summary

So we will end up with a distribution for drawing lots and inside that with a distribution of different outcomes. We can sum these up based on our needs, for example if we care only about $x$, then we need to sum up the probabilities of winning $(0 \cdot r_x)x$, $(1 \cdot r_x)x$, ..., $(L_{max} \cdot r_x)x$ and we end up with a nice distribution for $x$. We can even draw the different types of lotteries on the same $p(S_x)$ - $S_x$ distribution chart though in the case of different $r_x$ values we'll need to rather use ranges for this chart to be able to compare them. If we care about both $e$ and $x$ or $x$ and $y$, then we can try to draw a 3d surface for the probabilities, but it is easier to sum them up separately and draw it that way. We lose some covariance info this way, so for example if the probability of $x$ is always low when the probability of $y$ is high or vice-versa, then we won't see it on these 2d charts, while we would be able to see it on the 3d surface chart. So in theory I could write a nice program for this, in practice, I was just curious how this can be done, in practice I'll use the original formula for the average, because it is simple, fast and according to my simulations the deviation is not very high, maybe around 20% in most of the cases.

I hope this was not completely wrong, it was fun to think it through.